# Is there any alternative to echo daemon to display ip?

Tags: linux, ip, daemon, echo

Is there any alternative to echo daemon to display ip instead of given string?

For ex:
my ip = 80.1.2.3

server ip = 1.2.3.4

```
root@my-machine bash$ telnet 1.2.3.4
Trying 1.2.3.4...
Connected to 1.2.3.4.
Escape character is '^]'.
80.1.2.3
```

Comment: What would you need this for? This sounds like a case of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It might be better to ask a question about what you *actually* want to achieve using this.

Comment: I got my monitoring server, also i got lots of clients behind the NAT all over the world. Of course there are a lot of different network configurations. So I want to know their external ip. (clients can connect to server)

Comment: There are [web services](http://ipecho.net/plain), which do this. From a shell you could get the the external IP via for instance `wget http://ipecho.net/plain -O - -q ; echo`

Comment: unfortunately there is no access to ipecho.net =(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a small implementation of what you want in Python (run it as `server.py <port>`:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket
import sys

_, port = sys.argv

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(("0.0.0.0", int(port)))
sock.listen(1)

while True:
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    ip, port = addr
    conn.send(ip.encode("ascii") + b"\n")
    conn.close()
```

```
$ ./server.py 1234 &
[1] 20315
$ nc localhost 1234
127.0.0.1
$
```

Answer (score 2):

With `socat`:

```
socat tcp-listen:12345,reuseaddr,fork system:'echo "$SOCAT_PEERADDR"'
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, **no**. The Echo Protocol description in [RFC 862](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc862) is very simple and unambigious:

> TCP Based Echo Service

> One echo service is defined as a connection based application on TCP.
> A server listens for TCP connections on TCP port 7.  Once a
> connection is established any data received is sent back.  This
> continues until the calling user terminates the connection.
>
> UDP Based Echo Service
>
> Another echo service is defined as a datagram based application on
> UDP.  A server listens for UDP datagrams on UDP port 7.  When a
> datagram is received, the data from it is sent back in an answering
> datagram.

Comment: Yeah, I know it. So is there a kind of echo service that will provide me with external ip like ipecho.net/plain, but on tcp layer level.